# Python Class attributes are not initialized at the property.setter when the class itself is initialized

Tags: python-3.x

I understand that the property() built-in function overrides the **init**() constructor when it comes
to set instance variables, but why doesn't it change the self.y variable here?, although the **init**()
constructor is overridden successfully the print statement in the setx function proves that.

But when I use c.x, c.y works just fine.

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = None
        self.x = x
        self.y = 0

    def getx(self):
        return self._x

    def setx(self, value):
        print("Setting x")
        self._x = value
        self.y = self._x * 5

    x = property(getx, setx)

c = C(50)
print("x", c.x)
print("y", c.y)
```

It prints:
x 50
y 0

Comment: You change `y` in `__init__` **after** changing `x`, so its value is overwritten.

Comment: "I understand that the property() built-in function overrides the init() constructor " no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `self.y = 0` in front of `self.x = x`:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = None
        self.y = 0
        self.x = x


    def getx(self):
        return self._x

    def setx(self, value):
        print("Setting x")
        self._x = value
        self.y = self._x * 5

    x = property(getx, setx)

c = C(50)
print("x", c.x)
print("y", c.y)
```

Then, the output will be:

```
Setting x
x 50 
y 250
```

You got the `y 0` only because you set `self.y` first in the `setx` function, and then, you set it to `0` after that.